# Is this a C++ Semaphore?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

I have a thread-save-resource (a OpenCl-Command Queue to a device),but i want restrict the number of threads that have access to this ressource at the same time(i want to calculate on my cpu if the gpu command-queue is 'to full'). Unfortunately i'm relatively new to c++11 atomic operations. So i want to know if the following source code works as intended.

```
class SpinSemaphore{
public:
    SpinSemaphore(int max_count):
       _cnt(0),
       _max_cnt(max_count){}

    bool try_lock(){
       bool run = true;
       while(run){
           int cnt = _cnt.load();
           if(++cnt > _max_cnt) return false;

           run = !std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&_cnt, &cnt,
            std::memory_order_acquire);
       }
       return true;
   }

void unlock(){
    --_cnt;
}

private:
   std::atomic<int>     _cnt;
   int              _max_cnt;
};

//

SpinSemaphore m(4);

void foo(){ //..
   if(m.try_lock()){//..
      my_queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(/**/);
   }
   else
       //fallback

}
```

Comment: "multi-reader; no writer" - doesn't need locking then does it?

Comment: the intent is to limit the number of reader. I changed the topic to underline this.

Comment: Then what you want is a semaphore.  [Here's](http://cpprealm.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/c11-new-features-testing.html) an impl that uses the std::condition - available in C++11

Comment: sorry, seems so. I confused myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that won't behave as expected - consider the situation where 2 threads get to 
`int cnt = _cnt.load();` at the same time.  They will both read the same value, and both set the counter to the same value, even though it might be that only 1 of them should've got though.

That might be considered an acceptably rare occurrence for you to ignore, apart from when you unlock, your count will become negative.

Comment: Is there a way to fix it

Comment: try int cnt = ++_cnt which will reserve the value, and on failure you can 'unlock'.  This isn't perfect either, since if 1 thread tries to lock, one unlocks, and another locks, the result could be that both threads fail to obtain a lock, but it will at least make sure that you never offer the lock to too many threads.

Answer (score 0):

might by a typo, but you use atomic_compare_exchange_weak() wrong

what you need is

```
do {
   old=_cnt.load();
   new=old+1;
   if (new > _max_cnt) return false;
} while (!_cnt.compare_exchange_weak(&old,new));
```

imagine obj.compare_exchange_weak(old,new) as an atomic-Compare_And_Swap()-function

```
bool Compare_And_Swap() {
    if (obj == old) {
        obj = new;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```